# Use designation in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to write something about the smart city.

> smart city uses digital technologies or information and communication technologies (ICT) to enhance quality and performance of urban services, to reduce costs and resource consumption, and to engage more effectively and actively with its citizens.

can I use designation in this context when I talk about smart city:

Nowadays general population compete to achieve the designation of smart cities for its urban crowd?

Answer (score 1):

Smart City may need to be capitalized.  It feels like a proper noun.

I might place a colon after (ICT) to make it clear that the next bit is a comma list as I really wanted to read the ", to reduce consts " as "in order to reduce costs", which doesn't allow for the final item in the list.

And your use of designation works fine in the given sentence.

Comment: +1. In addition to being capitalized, it should be singular as you have it: "...compete to achieve the Smart City designation."